# Bitwise operators in Java acting on two bytes

Tags: java, c, types, bit-manipulation

This should be simple but I'm having trouble changing some C code that uses bitwise operators and shifts into Java.

In C I have:

```
unsigned short Color(byte r, byte g, byte b)
{
  return( ((unsigned short)g & 0x1F )<<10 | ((unsigned short)b & 0x1F)<<5 | (unsigned short)r & 0x1F);
}
```

This function, Color, returns 16bits where 15 of them represent three 5bit values for red, green, and blue color channels.  I'm trying to do something similar in Java except I'm having trouble with data types.

In java I have:

```
int r=someval, g=anotherval, b=yetanotherval;
```

And I want to convert these integers to a 2byte data type and use the same bitwise/shift operations as above.

What is the best way to approach this? I was thinking of a 2byte array but that seems unnecessary.

**edit**

So I gave it a try in Java with shorts but there still seems to be an issue.  I started simple with:

```
short r=someval, g=anotherval, b=yetanotherval;
short colorData = g & 0x001F;
```

But the compiler complains: "cannot convert from int to short"

Comment: Note, that casting to (unsigned short) in C does not have a sense at all, because arithmetic/bitwise operation arguments automaically promoted to [unsigned] int, and result of "&" will be int too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `short` type in Java as well, but it's always signed, there is no unsigned in Java.

Therefore, it might be better to use an `int`, so you don't need to use the sign bit to hold actual color data, which can be a bit (no pun intended!) confusing.

This should work as a starting point, at least:

```
int Color(int r, int g, int b)
{
  return ((g & 0x1F) << 10) | ((b & 0x1F) << 5) | (r & 0x1F);
}
```

I made the arguments `int` as well, for simplicity's sake.

**Update:** It sounds (and seems) as if you can actually use `short`, since you only need 15 bits for the color format. Then let's do that:

```
short Color(short r, short g, short b)
{
  return ((g & 0x1F) << 10) | ((b & 0x1F) << 5) | (r & 0x1F);
}
```

I haven't tried compiling the above, but it's likely that you'll get conversion errors and will need to add explicit `short` casts throughout to make it compile.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually not using the left most bit since I only need 15 of the 16 bits.  Would shorts work for me then?

Answer (score 2):

In java, all calculation operations, even with only types smaller than int, always result to an int, so you have to explicitly cast it back to short:

```
short colorData = (short)(g & 0x001F);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example

```
short r=someval, g=anotherval, b=yetanotherval;
short colorData = g & 0x001F;
```

Both g and the hex literal get automatically promoted to `int` because the logical and operator always works on and returns integers. You can of course cast the result back to `short`.

```
short colorData = (short)(g & 0x001F);
```

The same should work for the `char` datatype, which is in fact the only unsigned integer type on the JVM. I would recommend against using the char type in this way, unless this is an isolated performance/memory sensitive part of your program, since using `char` for arithmetic might seem strange and counterintuitive for other maintainers of the source.

Answer (score 1):

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

The Java char datatype is 2 bytes by default.

Comment: I gave char a try earlier but the compiler complains "cannot convert from char to int" whenever I try to do a bitwise 'and' on it with 0x001F.

Comment: This is getting a bit dirty now, but you could try specifying your hex like this "'\u001F'". This is the literal for char-values. But looking at your other comment, use the short if you only need 15 bit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using only 15 bits, the sign bit on the `short` data type will be no problem.